# WPF MVVM Light Toolbox with Entity framework c# simple linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm-light

What is the best way to use MVVM Light and Entity framework ?

1. I was create MVVM Light project.
2. I was add entity DB to Model folder. (DB.edmx)
3. I was add to MainWindow.xaml DataGrid and textbox.
4. What is next step for example to show user name in textbox or all data in DataGrid?
   Where I need add this logic?
   `dc.Employees.FirstOrDefault(s => s.EmployeesId == employeesId);` or `dc.Employees()`
   I need use "Model" or "Modelview" folder to add my logic?

I found some tutorial, but there are too difficult logic 2 time need create GetEmployees and ect.
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/wpf/1037/mvvm-light-wpf-model-view-viewmodel
http://dotnetpattern.com/mvvm-light-toolkit-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ViewModel` folder you would have a class `EmployeeViewModel`. This is what you need to build, and you don't care where that data comes from.

So you can have another class ( `EmployeeDataService` ) that creates the EmployeeViewModel. This is an intermediary class, that neither belongs in the `ViewModel`, nor the `Model` folder. You can place it in a folder like '`DataServices`'.

In Model you can have a method that returns an Employee:

```
    public Employee GetEmployee(){
    ...        
        return dc.Employees.FirstOrDefault(s => s.EmployeesId == employeesId);
    ...
    }
```

Then, in `DataServices\EmployeeDataService.cs` you can have:

```
public EmployeeViewModel GetEmployeeViewModel(id){
     Employee employeeModel = ModelClass.GetEmployee(id);
     EmployeeViewModel employeeVm = ' ..code to build an EmployeeViewModel from employeeModel
     return employeeVm;
}
```

Comment: So: `DB` > `Entity Framework` > `Model`(GetEmployee()) > `DataServices`(GetEmployeeViewModel(id)) > `ViewModel`(GetEmployee) > `View`(DataGrid) ? You offer do like in 1st link in tutorial? They create `Service` folder. Did I need create GetEmployee in Model, is not enoth Entity EDMF for that?

Comment: Yes, you got it right: in order to keep the ViewModel and the Model separate, you need a third component ( the 'Service' class ) that will relay the calls between the two. That way you can safely modify the implementation of the Model without impacting the ViewModel ( ad vice versa ).